# Why is my interrupt so slow/inconsistent? Arduino external interrupt as pedestrian crossing button

Tags: arduino, interrupts, button, c++

So this is the setup;

[image]

It's a traffic light system with 2 road lights and a pedestrian crossing. The normal sequence is
alternating between main road green and secondary road green. It reads these values from an array of binary-coded decimal values of the system states. I just thought it'd help to be able to use displayState[i] as a pointer to test and change lights.

When crosswalkButton is pressed, the system should immediately go into a new state, checking if the lights are currently red (if (displayState[i]= 37) { turnCrosswalkGreen} ), etc.
For now it's just set to flash every light, indicating the normal routine has been interrupted.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out why my interrupt is so inconsistent and slow. When the program
isn't doing anything else it works reasonably (but not very) well but when it is I often have to press the button several times to see any effect.

[image]

[link to my tinkerCAD project,](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/7hLuv5C2qdE-copy-of-copy-of-traffic-light-controller-/editel?sharecode=y49PY9O0Aeto7mwAe0857Or-qOWI4v_8qfCqv-veErA) dunno if that's gonna work... very confusing to get an accessible public version up...

Currently I have to spam clicks to get it to enter the interrupt routine. No idea why.
Given this is my first time using interrupts I'm almost definitely doing several things wrong.
If anyone can see anyone those things I'd be grateful for the help! Thanks!

```
// traffic light controller.
#define green1 3
#define orange1 4
#define red1 5
#define green2 6
#define orange2 7
#define red2 8
#define green3 9
#define red3 10
#define crossingButton 2

//global variables
int toggleState;
int lastButtonState = 1;
long unsigned int lastPress;
volatile int buttonFlag;
int debounceTime = 10;
int i = 0; // display state pointer.
int j = 0;  // I've never met this guy in my life. Is he with you?

//BCD traffic lights states. I did this so I can use the i in displayState[i]
// as a pointer to different data arrays

// 37 is when they're both red. I will hopefully loop that does this for me
// eg if (crossing)
int displayState[] =  {133, 69, 37, 49, 41, 37, 50, 42, 38};


void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
//setup pin modes
pinMode(green1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(orange1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(red1, OUTPUT);

pinMode(green2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(orange2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(red2, OUTPUT);

pinMode(green3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(red3, OUTPUT);

pinMode(crossingButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(crossingButton), ISR_button, CHANGE);
}

void loop(){
// normal routine goes here, but I want the crosswalk routine working first.

if ((millis() - lastPress) > debounceTime && buttonFlag){
  lastPress=millis(); //update lastPress
      if(digitalRead(crossingButton) == 0)
      {


        toggleState =! toggleState;
        allOn();
        delay(1000);
        allOff();
        delay(1000);
        allOn();
        delay(1000);
        allOff();
        delay(1000);
        allOn();
        digitalWrite(green1, toggleState);



        lastButtonState = 0; //record the last button state
      }
}
buttonFlag = 0;

        //run through the default sequence 
        for(i == 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
           showLights();
           delay(1000);
         }
         if(i = 6){
           i = 0;
         }


} //end main loop


void ISR_button ()  // this is the interrupt service routine
{
  buttonFlag = 1;  // barely anything running in the ISR, by design
}

void showLights (){
    //Serial.print("current display # : ");
    //Serial.println(i);
    digitalWrite(green1, (bitRead(displayState[i],7)));
    digitalWrite(orange1, (bitRead(displayState[i],6)));
    digitalWrite(red1, (bitRead(displayState[i],5)));
    digitalWrite(green2, (bitRead(displayState[i],4)));
    digitalWrite(orange2, (bitRead(displayState[i],3)));
    digitalWrite(red2, (bitRead(displayState[i],2)));
    digitalWrite(green3, (bitRead(displayState[i],1)));
    digitalWrite(red3, (bitRead(displayState[i],0)));

}

void allOn (){

      digitalWrite(green1, (bitRead(255,7)));
      digitalWrite(orange1, (bitRead(255,6)));
      digitalWrite(red1, (bitRead(255,5)));
      digitalWrite(green2, (bitRead(255,4)));
      digitalWrite(orange2, (bitRead(255,3)));
      digitalWrite(red2, (bitRead(255,2)));
      digitalWrite(green3, (bitRead(255,1)));
      digitalWrite(red3, (bitRead(255,0)));

}
void allOff (){

      digitalWrite(green1, (bitRead(0,7)));
      digitalWrite(orange1, (bitRead(0,6)));
      digitalWrite(red1, (bitRead(0,5)));
      digitalWrite(green2, (bitRead(0,4)));
      digitalWrite(orange2, (bitRead(0,3)));
      digitalWrite(red2, (bitRead(0,2)));
      digitalWrite(green3, (bitRead(0,1)));
      digitalWrite(red3, (bitRead(0,0)));

}
```

Comment: According to my experience with these crossing buttons, A pedestrian crossing button is supposed to be slow and inconsistent.  Sounds like you have it right by industry standards.

Comment: What have you done to debounce the button? When you press such a button, there is no single contact closure.

Comment: You need a pull-up resistor on the button input - 10K or so from the Arduino input pin to +5V.

Comment: Now that you solved the button press issue, I recommend you post your code to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are quite a few things which can be optimised in your code to make it a lot more readable, shorter and simpler to maintain. Note that your states are not BCD, they’re just binary (and would gain from using macros to populate them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
void loop(){
  if (buttonFlag){
    delay(100); // Debounce time
    buttonFlag = 0;
    
    toggleState =! toggleState;
    allOn();
    delay(1000);
    allOff();
    delay(1000);
    allOn();
    delay(1000);
    allOff();
    delay(1000);
    allOn();
    digitalWrite(green1, toggleState);
  }

  for(i == 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
     showLights();
     delay(1000);
  }
  if(i = 6){
    i = 0;
  }
} 

void ISR_button ()  // this is the interrupt service routine
{
  if(digitalRead(crossingButton) == 0)
    buttonFlag = 1;
}
```

This way, you set the flag only on the falling edge (pressed) and the debouncing is handled by resetting the flag after some delay.

This answer obviously doesn't give any explanation of why your code doesn't work well, but making the code less complicated is usually the best solution to any strange behavior.

Comment: Nope, you solved my problem. I amn't quite sure how this resolves it, but it's definitely related to that specific bit of code. For one thing, seems like I'm not understanding or using interrupts properly. 

Thanks sincerely for your solution! I will continue to read on this to try formalise that approach you've given.

Comment: The problem was if(digitalRead(crossingButton) == 0) in loop(). With all the other delays, by the time it gets there, the user has removed the finger from the button.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not strictly an answer, I'll cover some basics:

Firstly, you've use an *int* sized variable for your *buttonFlag*. You've declared this *volatile*. This means you've instructed the compiler to always read and write that variable rather than apply optimisations. Since this variable is shared between the isr and your main line code, this is what you want.

Since *buttonPress* is an *int* sized variable, it takes an AVR based Arduino multiple machine instructions to read or write the two bytes (16 bits) of your *int*. What would happen if you button interrupt hit whilst reading or writing this variable? Depending on the exact time the outcome could be of no consequence or worse, indeterminate. This illustrates the concept of *atomicity* - you want the read or write of these multiple bytes to be 'as one' or 'indivisible'. You need to take extra steps in your code to ensure this or for this piece of code, you could simply use a *char* or *uint8_t* sized variable and avoid at least one hazard due to atomicity.

I won't elaborate on the finer points as there's plenty written on the Interwebs about this. Also known as 'critical sections'.

The other problem I see is the use of external interrupts for a button press. Interrupts are used (mainly) to ensure a timely response to external stimulus, for a push button switch this sounds like a match made in heaven. The reality can be somewhat different.

Interrupts are good for situations where you really want micro/nano second response to an event. A push button switch as operated by a human is far from that criteria. Physically the switch can't operate much faster than around 100 times a second and the human less than that. Couple that with the phenomenon of 'switch bounce' the solution of using an external interrupt starts looking less appealing. The other critical 'gotcha' is you have no control over how fast that interrupt occurs. EMI, ESD and so on could cause rogue transitions on the signal and cause your microcontroller to stall or act erratically. So, in short, pushbuttons on external interrupts are generally bad juju. Ok if you want to wake the microcontroller from sleep, but that is all (there may be other reasons, but I'm making a generalisation).

A 'safer' alternative is to poll the switch input at a regular interval. This might be at 100 times a second (not critical - 100 is a convenient number) and you can count and otherwise time the detection of that switch. You can debounce and filter the input so when the rest of your code needs to determine if the switch has been pressed or not, it can be sure that the value is a true representation of the switch - not some transient or switch bounce.

Lastly, for your traffic light task, you really don't need interrupts at all. If you design your code as a finite state machine, you can read the switch input, filter it and compute your state machine in way less than 10ms (or 100 times/sec). If you need to time something, then keep a count of how many 10ms ticks. No need to sit in loops waiting for stuff to happen.

Comment: Thank you Kartman. I'll be googling all those keywords. 
We just covered interrupts in class, so I wanted to try it. I thought it'd get me around the fact that I have to program very big pauses into this sequence (main road light is to go green for 120 seconds) and the only way I've ever done this is with delay(). 

What the brief actually says about this is the wait time between button push and crossing green light is 10 seconds. I dunno how to get anywhere close to that without this current hack-job of an approach, but you've inspired me to go looking. Thanks a mil, again.